# Firebase Phone Auth not working on flutter app (release aab file)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, one-time-password, safetynet

I have tested the application in debug mode and release mode (.apk file). It works perfectly, but when I release an app bundle (.aab) for the play store using the same Keystore, it doesn't work.
I have registered SafetyNet and IntegrityAPI in firebase and added SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints of both debug and release Keystores.
I have added the SafetyNet API key in AndroidManifest like this:

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.safetynet.ATTEST_API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDTb8ah_xXsTsMdGSQjb2sg6csRUb5Vo6U"/>`

Got the API key from Cloud Console.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Did you change the SHA1 key for release mode?, you need to use a different key from debug mode.

Comment: Yes I have added SHA1 key for both debug and release mode

Comment: Hello, you find a solution?